# How to loop in array inside sql query in ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

A user has `languages`, which is an array of language names. I have this method:

```
def get_users_by_filtered_langauges(lang)
  users = []
  User.all.each do |u|
    u.languages.each do |l|
      users << u if lang.include?(l)
    end
  end
```

which takes `lang`, an array of language names, and returns the users whose `languages` include some language within `lang`. For example, if `first_user` has `languages` `["uk", "us"]` and `lang` is `["uk"]`, then the method's return value includes `first_user`.

Is there a way to minimize this and write a SQL query in a simpler way?

Comment: Please show us the table structure. Is `user.languages` just a serialized array field in `users`?

Comment: If `languages` is a `has_many` relationship, you should be able to do something like: `User.joins(:languages).where(languages: { name: langs })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Selecting *all* records is *always* an anti-pattern. One should select only records of interest. If you have problems writing the query selecting only records of interest, you should revise your database structure.
2. > write a SQL query in a simple way

That is relatively easy. For single `lang` to check it would be:

```
%q|SELECT * FROM users WHERE languages LIKE "%#{lang}%"|
```

3. Even using `all`, your method is abusing `each` for reducing the input.

In ruby it should be written as:

```
def get_users_by_filtered_langauges(*langs)
  # single lang
  # User.all.reject { |u| u.languages.include?(lang) }

  # disjunction
  User.all.reject { |u| (u.languages & langs).empty? }
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped alot.

Comment: Don't you have stray double quotes (which are for identifiers in standard SQL, not strings) in `LIKE "'%#{lang}%'"`? Also, if you have a serialized array then any query against that column is madness; if the array is a PostgreSQL array column then there are lots of operators to use.

Comment: @muistooshort indeed, thanks, I got lost in what is SQL string and what is ruby string, updated. The query is done against the single language; since I had no idea about the underlying DB engine, I provided the third variant.

Answer (score 0):

@mudasobwa's answer is right. But you could also do like this.

```
User.where("languages like '%?%'", lang)
```

Comment: This is not valid Ruby. You probably meant `"languages like '%?%'"`.

Comment: Right Thank you.